# How to apply get range in combination with i++

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Today I have come with something that I have been trying for quite some time now, but due to time issues, I do finally have decided to seek help.

For starters, I have this table:

| Name | Score year 1 | Score year 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |
|  |  |  |

Now, each name will have it´s own tablepages for various reasons not relevant for this, so this forces me to be a bit inventive.

I have already figured out how to automatically enter the sheets with this function:

```
function sheetnames() {
  var out = new Array()
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  for (var i=6; i<sheets.length ; i++) out.push( [ sheets[i].getName() ] )
  return out 
}
```

Now, What I want to know if, and if so how, one can use this to get the scores for each year once the sheet is made.

For sake of clarity, I will outline it this way.

I want the function to grab a bunch of values from any sheets that would be included in the function above automatically.

if I make the sheet Alex and 100+ and enter the values on these sheets, they should appear in this table.

Apologies if something is written erroneous, I am not an native English speaker.

Please feel free to ask questions for clarification.

Comment: The way your functionn `sheetnames` works right now, is that it returns an array with names of sheets like: ['sheet6','sheet7',...] also note it starts at `i=6` for some reason. Now this is what you have. But can you clarify what you want?

Comment: That was the intent. Sheets 1-5 are in use for other Data, so the relevant Sheets start at i=6. The question was, since I was about to get multiple hundred sheets which had a lot of data on them, not all of which was relevant to me. So, my intention was that I could make an function that would list each Sheet and get the relevant cells.

Basically, a function that lists all sheets past the 5th and writes out the cells A3, A5 and A6, for example, for each

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have n Sheets, all with a name and they all have a score for k years next to each other in the first row?

Why are you starting at the 5th Sheet?

I never had anything to do with google services and what not, but after a look in their docs, I found a function that gets the content of an area:

```
getSheetValues(startRow, startColumn, numRows, numColumns)
```

It returns a two dimensional array of the Values. You should test if the columns are the first index or the second. The following code assumes an array of rows (column are the second index). Take everything with a chunk of salt, I know Javascript for like 2 weeks and just googled a bunch of stuff.

```
function sheetnames() {
    var out = new Array();
    var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  
    for (var i=6; i<sheets.length ; i++) { //if you want to start at the 5th sheet otherwise i=0

        var columns = sheets[i].getLastColumn();   // gets the last column with content (the length)
        var content = sheets[i].getSheetValues(0, 0, 1, columns)[0]; // get one row
        var newRow = content.unshift(sheets[i].getName());

        out.push(newRow);
    }
    return out 
}
```